# Filter URLs of websites with adult content

Tags: php, javascript

What I was trying to do was have users type in their favorite sites in a form and submit it onto their profile

What I wanted to ban was pornographic sites, but since there are most likely thousands of those sites out there, what is the best way of banning them?

My first option was using javascript like this one

```
var bad_sites_arr=new Array("bad.com","adult.com");
```

but if I did this, I would have to type every single site and put them in quotes separated by a space and comma. This would be tedious and very time-consuming but also very effective.

My question was, is there another way of banning adult sites?

Comment: This would be totally ineffective.  New adult sites are created constantly.  It would be more than a full time job to keep adding URLs this way.

Comment: I didn't think of that. So its best not to bother probably lol

Comment: There are other methods (e.g. implementing terms-of-service descriptions and having a manual reporting mechanism).  Usually a combination of methods is best.  Each one will erode the problem a little further, but beware of diminishing returns.  This is very similar to the level of piracy or security countermeasures you employ - too much will annoy customers/users, but too little is just begging for problems.  If you want mechanical removal, you should try to implement smarter filters, in addition to, or instead of a simple black list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 is there another way of banning adult sites?
```

You might want to implement a simple "Report this link" type of moderation.  That way, you have the users themselves policing other users.  You only need to get involved if a link is reported.

You could even have a link automatically removed if it is reported by 3 or more people.

Comment: This is a very stackoverflow like solution ;) +1

Answer (score 5):

You could subscribe to a filtering service, require moderation of unknown sites, or just give up and ban folks who wind up abusing it. Whatever you do, JavaScript isn't the way to do it, as that's under control of the user.

Comment: So if I did use javascript, they could turn it off and type in a site?

Comment: That's right.  Plus, if you do it in javascript, you'll need to send your entire list of bad sites to the user.  That will take a while for them to download.  That sort of thing is best done server side.

Comment: Might as well ban the users instead of banning urls then. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

http://akismet.com/

> Akismet filters out your comment and track-back spam for you, so you
>   can focus on more important things.

This will try to filter out all spam instead of just porn. You can make this even stronger by having user first having to pass captcha. If you don't like this you could  [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) in stead just like stackoverflow.com does. To have reputation in place you first need to authenticate users(I suggest OpenID).

P.S: banning all spam is almost impossible(reputation will get you a long way I think). You could  moderate posts which look flakky first, but then you probably also will have some [false positive](http://www.securelist.com/en/glossary?glossid=153654932) or some porn links will get trough probably.